Taking 2 ARRAY_AGG intances from BQ and getting result back
Say I have 2 queries as below in Big Query
Query1:
select ARRAY_AGG(distinct col1)  as col1_list from table1
Query2:
select ARRAY_AGG(distinct col2)  as col2_list from table1
How do I return the response to caller because I do not wish to make 2 calls. If I do a union of the two, the column names are not what I want in response.
Is anything like below possible to achieve and how:
{"col1_list":[v1,v2], "col2_list": [v3,v4]}
Or instead of ARRAY_AGG I must use something else to achieve the result?

Try example
with src as(
  select 'v1-1' col1, 'v2-1' col2
  union all
  select 'v1-2' col1, 'v2-2' col2
  union all
  select 'v1-2' col1, 'v2-2' col2
  union all
  select 'v1-3' col1, 'v2-3' col2
  union all
  select 'v1-1' col1, 'v2-1' col2
)
select  
   array_agg(distinct col1) as col1list
  ,array_agg(distinct col2) as col2list
from src;




col1list
col2list




"[v1-1,v1-2,v1-3]"
"[v2-1,v2-2,v2-3]"



Or
select  
  json_object('col1list',array_agg(distinct col1)
             ,'col2list',array_agg(distinct col2) 
           ) as json_data
from src;




json_data




"{""col1list"":[""v1-1"",""v1-2"",""v1-3""],""col2list"":[""v2-1"",""v2-2"",""v2-3""]}"




As you want an JSON you can use JSON_OBJECT to create it
SELECT JSON_OBJECT('col1_list',  (select ARRAY_AGG(distinct col1)  from table)
, 'col2_list', (select ARRAY_AGG(distinct col2)  from table1)) AS json_data

